# Lists in Unity2D - Issue Adding

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to add an item into a list within my LevelManager script. It is for an enemy that when he dies, a prefab of his corpse is added with the necessary colliders etc for the LevelManager to handle.

The enemy script is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator anim;
    public GameObject deadGuy;
    public LevelManager manager;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        manager = GetComponent<LevelManager>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(anim.GetBool("Dead"))
        {
            StartCoroutine("Die");
        }

    }

    private IEnumerator Die()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length);
        Instantiate(deadGuy, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        manager.worldObjects.Add(deadGuy);
        DestroyObject(gameObject);
    }
}
```

The death animation plays and then the prefab is added as "Dead Guy (clone)" in the hierarchy but then the animation plays again and more prefabs are instantiated. However if I remove this line of code:

```
manager.worldObjects.Add(deadGuy);
```

Then the animation plays, the prefab is added and the enemy object is deleted.

Comment: I think you need another bool in your update to only start the coroutine once.

Comment: If the GameObject is being destroyed though it shouldn't run again as the enemy script is attached to the enemy object. It works if the line of code is removed: 

manager.worldObjects.Add(deadGuy);

so it seems that line is preventing it reaching the next line where it destroys the gameObject itself unless it is removed

Answer (score 1):

So it seems the best method was to take the handling of the corpse into another script and attach it to the prefab. Therefore I could instantiate the prefab, delete the gameObject that called for the instantiate and do without the List in Level Manager

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Solution**

As mentioned in the comments; it's because the bool `Dead` is set to true by the animator, and for every call to `Update` by Unity, a new *dead player* is created. The alive player GameObject isn't being destroyed until after the death animation of the dead player is played, and update will be called many times during that animation.

To fix this, add a bool to your class such as;

```
private bool m_instantiatedDeadPlayer;
```

And then in your update loop, change the if statement to be;

```
public void Update (
{
    if(anim.GetBool("Dead") && !m_instantiatedDeadPlayer)
    {
        m_instantiatedDeadPlayer = true;
        StartCoroutine("Die");
    }
}
```

---

**Complicated Solution**

A better but more complicated approach would be to have the death animation included in the same Animator as your alive enemy, to activate the necessary colliders etc. and to have the transition from the current alive animation to the dead animation be a [Trigger](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) that you set when the enemies health is equal to 0. This is assuming you have a method attached to the enemy for taking damage, which would look something like this;

```
public void ApplyDamage(int p_amount)
{
    if(!m_isDead)
    {
        m_health = Mathf.Clamp(m_health - p_amount, 0, 100);

        if(m_health == 0)
            m_animator.SetTrigger("Dead");
    }
}
```

You therefore eliminate the need for the Coroutine, instead adding the enemy to the list of objects when the enemy is spawned, and whenever you need all dead enemies, have a method that returns the private variable `m_isDead` attached to the enemy.

Hope this helps, let me know if you would like some more details.